# Is anyone doing asynchronous DB commits?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

Most of the longest (most time-consuming) logic I've encountered basically involves two things: sending email and committing items to the database.

Is there any kind of built-in mechanism for doing these things asynchronously so as not to slow down page load?

Validation should be handled synchronously, but it really seems that the most performant way to email and write to the database should be asynchronously.

For example, let's say that I want to track pageviews. Thus, every time I get a view, I do:

```
pv = PageView.objects.get(page = request.path)
pv.views = pv.views + 1
pv.save() # SLOWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Is it natural to think that I should speed this up by making the whole process asynchronous?

Comment: It really shouldn't be slow ... I can push upwards of 20k *updates* per second on SQLite (but only about 30 *commits* per second) ... so where does the slowness come from? At the final level, the db commit *must* be synchronous (somewhere) for ACID, which might screw up with error handling? :( [I don't use django at all.]

Comment: "Is it natural to think that I should speed this up by making the whole process asynchronous?"  No.  It's natural to gather data to determine the exact source of the performance problem.  Please gather some facts, and please post the details of what's really happening.

Comment: So you're the guy who writes the comment tracking code for Yahoo :-).  Nothing but lost posts and "Oops, try again" messages.  Seriously, you're going to need to sync up sometime - if you're doing 100 pageviews per second but only 1 commit per second, your queue will either expand without limit or data will fall in the bitbucket, neither of which is a desirable outcome.

Comment: @Dave I believe a transactional database solves that problem.

Comment: Tk it's natural to think this way indeed, take a look at @dkamins's answer. No sense in slowing down the site for things that can be executed at a later time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/).  It gives you asynchronous workers to offload tasks exactly like you're asking about:  sending e-mails, counting page views, etc.  It was originally designed to work only with Django, but now works in other environments too.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I wasn't on crazy pills when I was looking to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern to update the text index (which is slow), since this can be done in background. This way the user sees a fast response time:

```
    # create empty file
    dir=os.path.join(settings.DT.HOME, 'var', 'belege-changed')
    file=os.path.join(dir, str(self.id))
    fd=open(file, 'a') # like "touch" shell command
    fd.close()
```

A cron-job scans this directory every N minutes and updates the text index.

In your case, I would write the request.path to a file, and update the PageView model in background. This would improve the performance, since you don't need to hit the database for every increment operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a python ThreadPool and assign the writes to the database. Although GIL prevent the Python threads to work concurrently this allow to continue the response flow before the write is finished.

I use this technique when the result of the write is not important to render the response.

Of course, if you want to post request and want to return a 201, this is not a god practice.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.mongodb.org/ can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the link to MongoDB, I've been reading into it a lot lately. Unfortunately, this really doesn't address my problem, as I'm using a SQL database at the moment.

Comment: I attempted to to change it to "MongoDB can do this" but then it's too short of answer for SO. lol.

Comment: -1 because changing to Mongo is a huge, radical change to the core of the project (replacing the whole db backend to a NoSQL db) and its not a rational solution to a simple question such as "how to do async writes". I doubt anyone reading this answer will benefit anything from it.